# Grails 2.2.x - Dependency resolution using multiple custom repositories

Tags: maven, grails, groovy, grails-2.0, rad

I am trying to get dependency resolution work in Grails 2.2 using multiple customer repositories.

Currently, I am able to specify credentials section only once for a repository. What should be the configuration, if I work with multiple repositories ?

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    repositories { ... }
    credentials {
        realm = " "
        host = " "
        username = " "
        password = " "
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like putting credentials in settings.groovy only works for a single repo and not for multiple repos.

So, Inside your `BuildConfig.groovy`, in the "repositories" block, add code like this:

```
final properties = new Properties()
properties.load(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.grails/maven.properties"))
final mavenUsername = properties.getProperty("user")
final mavenPassword = properties.getProperty("password")

mavenRepo ("http://repo.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local") {
    auth([
        username: mavenUsername,
        password: mavenPassword
    ])
}
mavenRepo ("http://repo.mycompany.com:8081/artifactory/remote-repos") {
    auth([
        username: mavenUsername,
        password: mavenPassword
    ])
}
```

You can refer [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.5/guide/conf.html#dependencyRepositories) and [this](http://coding-kaizen.blogspot.com/2014/01/grails-maven-repo-credentials.html) for more information

Hope it helps you.